# Can`t select new version of app for TestFlight testing in iTunesConnect: operation_failed, version: undefined

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

New version of application shown in TestFlight after uploading it via Xcode 7 but I can`t apply it for internal testing. I can select it in list of versions, but iTunesConnect shows error after i click "Save" button.

Comment: I am having this issue too. I will be resubmitting and will update here with the outcome.

Comment: Receiving a '500 (Internal Server Error)' in the xhr with the following error being logged by Apple: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'availableExportCompliances' of undefined' I'd guess this is an issue with the whole of iTunes Connect and not a localised one.

Comment: I had the same problem and it worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/35990080/1482768