# Operation_failed: When I select new version for internal testing in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

When I try to select the new version for Internal testing in iTunesConnect. It shows me an error "Operation_failed". But there is no reason why this error happens?

In the the version selecting dialog box, there is an warning message "Your latest build is still in processing". From this warning message, I can understand that, the latest build is still in processing state, but when I check in the Activity screen, (processing) indication is not displaying.

I also checked this issue for couple of hours, I have found the link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23943?tstart=0, but in this link I didn't get any solution.

Comment: did you found any solution to this ?

Comment: @Leena: No i didn't get any solution. I think it is problem in iTunesConnect itself.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but you can use Application Loader to upload your app. This helped me with "operation_failed" error.

Comment: I tried by using Application loader also. But I face  the same problem.

Comment: Can you, please, try to clear checkbox "include bitcode" at the bottom of the summary screen (in App Loader)

Comment: When I use the application loader, I am not able to select the version for internal testing.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling testing and enabling it again fixed this problem for me. Just select "Not Available for Testing" -> Save -> Select version to test -> choose version -> Save

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is in iTunesConnect. Because after 2 or 3 days, I have uploaded my new version. It gets successfully uploaded and allow me to select the version for Internal testing. I didn't face the same issue.

Thanks for all you answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Expire all builds
2. Delete all users added as testers to that app
3. Delete all information under Testflight - General Information - Test information make sure it's black on all fields.